# Need some guidances for using JSARtoolkit with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, artoolkit

Firstly, I am new to both JSARToolkit and three.js. So, I am asking this post to get some guidances to implement my requirements, which is like following:

1. Use a camera to detect a physical object.
2. If that object is right, the system will generate a 3D-barcode (this will be a marker).
3. The 3D-camera will detect that newly generated barcode and render an augmented object.

I found [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjjuFBcg0_Y) which is similar to what I want. However, as a newbie, I have no idea how to do and what I should start.

Comment: Your question is too broad and does not belong on SO. I'd suggest you don't dive in, learn one requirement such as three.js first. Once you're comfortable with that, start expanding your knowledge. The best way to tackle a large problem is always one small problem at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What is "SO"?

Comment: Try the ARToolKit forum: http://artoolkit.org/community/forums/viewforum.php?f=32&sid=54251a0960e8093b8e31da5910e058d3